# error in media wiki php code

Tags: php

```
$wgAuth = new HttpAuthPlugin();  //After this line, control is not reachin the next line, not printin the next log.

error_log("JITEN TEST :WGAUTH object created, Value of wgAuth is :" . $wgAuth . "\n", 3, $logfile);

$wgHooks['UserLoadFromSession'][] = array($wgAuth,'autoAuthenticate');
error_log("JITEN TEST :Value of wgAuth is :" . $wgAuth . "\n", 3, $logfile);
```

In the above case the code after `$wgAuth = new HttpAuthPlugin();`  is not getting executed.

Comment: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HttpAuth

Answer (score 1):

According to the article on writing your own [AuthPlugin](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classAuthPlugin.html), the class is called `AuthPlugin` not `HttpAuthPlugin`.

So it seems you should be using the code:

```
$wgAuth = new AuthPlugin();
```

Is this class coming from a third-party?

Comment: yes it is a third party plugin mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HttpAuth 

HttpAuthPlugin.php is the extension, for Mediawiki.The mentioned code changes have been implemented inside LocalSettings.php and HttpAuthPlugin.php

Comment: What happens if you put the HttpAuthPlugin init into a conditional? Like: `if(!($wgAuth = new HttpAuthPlugin())) {echo "Error: Object Not created";}`

Comment: I have used a condition as follows : if(!($wgAuth = new HttpAuthPlugin())) { error_log("Error: Object Not created" . "\n", 3, $logfile); } else { error_log("Object created" . "\n", 3, $logfile); } But, it is not giving any output, seems like it is stuck inside the class HttpAuthPlugin, while creating an object